# Reference: where to find solved exercises on PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I am interested in PDE's, but this topic is SO huge and has so many different approaches that starting to study it is really, really confusing and kinda scaring. 
As I said this topic is huge and there are countless books out there that give some ways of dealing with PDE's, some of them even provide examples of problems with solutions, but there aren't that many. I was wondering: is there a book of solved exercises on PDE's?
It doesn't have to develop the theory (many other books do that already), but just give you some problems and make you see how to deal with them with different approaches.

I know my request is a bit vague, but I am just entering this topic and having a solid reference for understanding many techniques would be extremely useful.

Comment: Perhaps you'll find interesting this [Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277083/collections-of-examples-and-counterexamples-in-real-complex-functional-analy).

Comment: @DanieleTampieri absolutely. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: solved problems and exercises on PDEs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421370/reference-solved-problems-and-exercises-on-pdes)